# how to get the VorbisFormat2

Tags: directshow, ogg, ms-media-foundation, decoder, oggvorbis

I try to decoder ogg in mediafoundation. now I have see the dshow filter but I don't understand how to create VORBISFORMAT2

```
struct VORBISFORMAT2
{
unsigned long channels;
unsigned long samplesPerSec;
unsigned long bitsPerSample;
unsigned long headerSize[3];  // 0: Identification, 1: Comment, 2: CodecSetup
};

VorbisDecodeInputPin::SetMediaType(const CMediaType* inMediaType) 
{
  ...
  mVorbisDecoder.Init(reinterpret_cast<VORBISFORMAT2*>(inMediaType->pbFormat));
}
```

I don't know how to get inMediaType->pbFormat  in mediafoundation.
or how to get the VORBISFORMAT2‘s header by use libvorbis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve it now by use vorbis_analysis_headerout